# How to change background on ggplot line chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the background on my line plot. I'd like to see two options. One with no grid at all. And another where the background is white but the gridlines are gray.
`limits <- data.frame( year = c(1934, 1950, 1966, 1974, 1980, 1987, 2006, 2010,  2011,  2013, 2016, 2019,2020, 2021, 2022), limit = c(2500, 10000, 15000, 40000, 100000, 100000, 100000,250000, 250000,250000, 250000, 250000, 250000,  250000, 250000) )`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(limits, aes(x = year, y = limit)) +
geom_line(color="chartreuse2", lwd=1.5) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1940, 2020, by = 20))  +
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0("$", format(x, 
big.mark = ",",    scientific = FALSE))) +
labs(x = "", y = "", title ="Limits Over Time") enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ggthemes` package, you can get no lines at all with `theme_tufte()`, like this:

```
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(limits, aes(x = year, y = limit)) +
  geom_line(color="chartreuse2", lwd=1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1940, 2020, by = 20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0("$", 
                                                 format(x,
                                                        big.mark = ",",
                                                        scientific = FALSE))) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", title ="Limits Over Time") +
  theme_tufte()
```

The `theme_bw()` might be an option for the other one.

```
ggplot(limits, aes(x = year, y = limit)) +
  geom_line(color="chartreuse2", lwd=1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1940, 2020, by = 20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0("$", 
                                                 format(x,
                                                        big.mark = ",",
                                                        scientific = FALSE))) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", title ="Limits Over Time") +
  theme_bw()
```

You can also modify the different elements of the background yourself, here is a useful post:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/how-to-change-background-color-in-ggplot2-3/